# Generate Random Data for Cassandra DB

Tags: java, random, cassandra

I have a big data project for school that requires us to build and query a 8 node Cassandra system. The system must contain at least seven terabytes of data. I have to generate all this data myself. There is no requirement that the data be "relevant" to the assignment -- ie each column can just be a random int. That being said it is required that each value is random or based on a random sequence.

So, I wrote a simple java program to just generate random `ints`. I can generate `~200 MB` of random test data in `~120s`. Now unless my math is off, then I think I'm in a pickle.

There are `35000` `200MB` units in `7 terabytes`.

35000 * 120 = `4 200 000 seconds`

4 200 000 / 3600 ~ `1167hours`

1167 / 24 = `49 days`

So, it appears that it will take 49 days to generate all the test data needed. Obviously, this is impractical. I'm looking for suggestions that will increase the rate at which I can generate data.

I've considered/considering:

> setting replication factor to 8 to reduce the amount of data needed to be generated, and also running the data generation program on all 8 nodes.

edit: how I'm generating the data

```
private void initializeCols(){
    cols = new ArrayList<Generator>();
    cols.add(new IntGenerator(400));
}

public ArrayList<String> generatePage(){
    ArrayList<String> page = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < PAGE_SIZE; i++){
        line = "";
        for(Generator column : cols){
            line += column.gen();
        }
        page.add(line);
    }
    return page;
}
```

originally I was generating more `test specific` data like `phone numbers` etc. but then I decided to just generate random `ints` in order to shave some time off -- not much savings. Here is the `IntGenerator` class.

```
public IntGenerator(int series){
    this.series = series;
}

public String gen(){
    String output = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < series; i++){
        output += Integer.toString(randomInt(1,1000));
        output += SEPERATOR; 
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Please post how you're generating the data and how you're storing it in the db.

Comment: I haven't gotten around to loading the data into the db, but the schema is a `single table` with `400 columns` which at this point are all going to be `int` values.

Comment: With the amount of concatenation going on in your loops, have you thought about using StringBuilder to squeeze more juice out of it?

Comment: Don't dare to concatenate Strings that way in such huge amounts! :) Use StringBuilder as @OblivionCreations mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are performing a lot of concatenation in loops, I highly recommend you check out [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). It will dramatically increase the speed of your loops. For example,

```
public String gen(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < series; i++){
        sb.append(Integer.toString(randomInt(1,1000)));
        sb.append(SEPERATOR); 
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And you should do similar in your generatePage method as well.

Answer (score 8):

Use [cassandra stress 2.1](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/improved-cassandra-2-1-stress-tool-benchmark-any-schema)

And this [tool](http://www.sestevez.com/sestevez/CASTableSizer/) to generate your yaml.

You'll have random data in C* in minutes, no coding!

Comment: omg where were you a few weeks ago! I ended up writing SSTables and loading them via JMX, but my god is this link of yours amazing! I think I might share it with my prof, so that future students will have an easier time.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you taking a c* course?

Comment: Well I'm not talking a C* course per say. I'm doing Databases II at the University of Alberta, and as an optional project I'm supposed to build a simple NoSQL system. We were able to choose any NoSQL system, and our group went with C* because there was a tutorial about how to set up a cluster given in a lab.

Answer (score -1):

Speed in volume as well as more data realism can be had via third-party test data tools. This one (RowGen) creates flat files you can copy into DataStax; see:

[Creating Test Data for Cassandra DataStax](http://www.iri.com/blog/test-data/creating-test-data-for-cassandra-datastax/)